# VBScript ASP and Paypal IPN problems

Tags: asp.net, paypal, vbscript, paypal-ipn

Dear Mentors and Gurus,

My question is basic, it is similar to other IPN questions on here, but I have yet to see an answer related to VBScript (seems PHP is a bit lower level so more work to do to post the response properly- or so I think).
I'm using the PayPal sample code for ASP/VBScript to create a IPN listener.   Using the Paypal simulator, I make a call to my script.  I don't seem to be able to get a "VERIFIED" response from Paypal, always 'INVALID'.  I've read a number of things on the internet (like the charset) and tried these with no progress.  Answers regarding charset differences seem to be older as I don't see any place to control charset, especially via the simulator.  I'm not seeing a URL Encoding issue as what is posted back is still/already encoded (the GMT + issue doesn't seem to be present as described in other IPN problems).
  I post to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr (see code) and that gives me a handshake, but posts to sandbox (commented out) do not result in handshake.  Absolutely, Paypal is communicating with my website, I have modified the code to dump out all the form values received into a text file.  Just can't ever get a "VERIFIED" response.
I thought the code provided on GitHub would be 'ready to go'.  What noobie thing am I missing?

```
    <%@LANGUAGE="VBScript"%>
<%
Dim Item_name, Item_number, Payment_status, Payment_amount
Dim Txn_id, Receiver_email, Payer_email
Dim objHttp, str
' read post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'

' post back to PayPal system to validate
'set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
'set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0")
set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
str = Request.Form & "&cmd=_notify-validate"
objHttp.open "POST", "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr", false
'objHttp.open "POST", "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr", false
'objHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
'objHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

objHttp.Send str
' assign posted variables to local variables
'Dim responseText : responseText = objHttp.responseText
Item_name = Request.Form("item_name")
Item_number = Request.Form("item_number")
Payment_status = Request.Form("payment_status")
Payment_amount = Request.Form("mc_gross")
Payment_currency = Request.Form("mc_currency")
Txn_id = Request.Form("txn_id")
Receiver_email = Request.Form("receiver_email")
Payer_email = Request.Form("payer_email")


Dim Folderpath, fs, fPayPal, fPP, FormArray, FormStr
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Folderpath=server.mappath(".\mdb") 
fPayPal=Folderpath &"\paypal.txt"
'Payer_email = "test@test.com"
Response.Write "File:" & fPayPal
Set fPP = fs.CreateTextFile(fPayPal,True)
fPP.WriteLine("PayPal")
fPP.WriteLine(str)
FormArray = Split(str, "&", -1, 1)
for each FormStr in FormArray
fPP.WriteLine(FormStr)
Next

' Check notification validation
if (objHttp.status <> 200 ) then
' HTTP error handling
 'Response.Write "Error:"
 fPP.WriteLine("Status <> 200")
elseif (objHttp.responseText = "VERIFIED") then
 fPP.WriteLine("VERIFIED")
 fPP.WriteLine(Payer_email)
' check that Payment_status=Completed
' check that Txn_id has not been previously processed
' check that Receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
' check that Payment_amount/Payment_currency are correct
' process payment
elseif (objHttp.responseText = "INVALID") then
' log for manual investigation
' Response.Write "INVALID"
  fPP.WriteLine("INVALID")
else
' Response.Write "OTHER ERROR"
   fPP.WriteLine("OTHER ERROR")
end if

set objHttp = nothing
fPP.Close
Set fs=nothing
%>
```

Things you see commented out are things I tried or comments from the original code on github.  [Paypal IPN example code](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples)

Here's what the result is in paypal.txt, the file written by the code.  The last line is "INVALID" which is written because the responseText is set to "INVALID" by the POST call to paypal.

```
PayPal
payment_type=instant&payment_date=Mon%20Apr%2003%202017%2010%3A12%3A36%20GMT-0400%20%28Eastern%20Daylight%20Time%29&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=buyer@paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John%20Smith&address_country=United%20States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San%20Jose&address_street=123%20any%20street&business=seller@paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller@paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=seller@paypalsandbox.com&residence_country=US&item_name1=something&item_number1=AK-1234&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&mc_gross_1=12.34&mc_handling=2.06&mc_handling1=1.67&mc_shipping=3.02&mc_shipping1=1.02&txn_type=cart&txn_id=283858647&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&test_ipn=1&verify_sign=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A4bCrzfIB.qeXiXSypZmZAhKwWUC&cmd=_notify-validate
payment_type=instant
payment_date=Mon%20Apr%2003%202017%2010%3A12%3A36%20GMT-0400%20%28Eastern%20Daylight%20Time%29
payment_status=Completed
address_status=confirmed
payer_status=verified
first_name=John
last_name=Smith
payer_email=buyer@paypalsandbox.com
payer_id=TESTBUYERID01
address_name=John%20Smith
address_country=United%20States
address_country_code=US
address_zip=95131
address_state=CA
address_city=San%20Jose
address_street=123%20any%20street
business=seller@paypalsandbox.com
receiver_email=seller@paypalsandbox.com
receiver_id=seller@paypalsandbox.com
residence_country=US
item_name1=something
item_number1=AK-1234
tax=2.02
mc_currency=USD
mc_fee=0.44
mc_gross=12.34
mc_gross_1=12.34
mc_handling=2.06
mc_handling1=1.67
mc_shipping=3.02
mc_shipping1=1.02
txn_type=cart
txn_id=283858647
notify_version=2.1
custom=xyz123
invoice=abc1234
test_ipn=1
verify_sign=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A4bCrzfIB.qeXiXSypZmZAhKwWUC
cmd=_notify-validate
INVALID
```

[image: paypal simulator response]

This response is only available when I post to paypal.  Posting to sandbox.paypal.com does not indicate a 'sent' or a 'handshake'.   I am using a remote/hosted website by a service provider, so the weblogs are not available to me until 48 hours later.  All the nice debug features I normally would have on my local webserver are not available (no method to sniff the raw data posted by Paypal or returned that I am aware of on the remote machine).

Answer (score 0):

I found this as a statement:
When you use the PayPal IPN Simulator, the response you get will always be Invalid.

Not in the documentation from what I can tell.  If someone can confirm, then this tidbit would have saved me a weekend of trial/error.

//Update
I have learned two things which I'll share with the community.  The proper URLs to use in 2017 are:
objHttp.open "POST", "https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr", false
or for live:
objHttp.open "POST", "https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr", false

What I believe the issue to be is that the Sandbox URL as of NOW only allows TLS 1.2 HTTPS connections (for sure you must use HTTPS and no longer HTTP).  The live paypal URL will required TLS 1.2 in June 2017.
This problem occurs at the objHttp.Send str.  It generates a 800c0005 500 error in your ASP as the Paypal Sandbox URL refuses the connection due to server using TLS 1.0 and Paypal requiring TLS 1.2.

As it turns out Godaddy (https://www.godaddy.com) hosting does not allow TLS 1.2 if you are an "older customer".   We started windows webhosting with them in 2009.  Rather than updating the server underneath our hosting to be current, as we're paying a service, they consider that we fractionally bought the 'old server' and are stuck with that. Now we need to pay to upgrade.  This is despite the monthly cost for a new customer for hosting on a normal up-to-date server actually being lower than what we have now.

Please be aware community.  I spent a week of time on this. You can't see the HTTPS handshake so a user is not going to know the limitations of the provider.

CONFIRMED. Worked once going onto a new (2017) server which supports TLS 1.2. Needed to start a new web-hosting because Godaddy will not update your existing account or the server software/OS underneath the website you have.

Comment: This is innacurate.  The simulator will return a verified IPN as long as it's functioning properly.  Unfortunately, sometimes the simulator simply doesn't function properly.  Based on your screenshot, though, that simulation should have returned a verified IPN as long as your script is doing the POST back to PayPal correctly.

Comment: well the code is there for the POST and it is straight from Paypal provided code. get incoming Form, add the "&cmd=_notify-validate" and post it back. It's some of the most simple coding I've encountered that does not produce the desired results.  We've used Paypal for years but this is the first foray into trying to get the customer's email from the payment system.